# Login script in javascript failed

Tags: javascript, php, authentication

Im creating login script which are based on javascript and PHP. But I had problem with it.

Whatever I send via form I will be redirected to user.php?u=loginfailed. It doesen't matter whether it is properly email and password (which I have in my database). As you can see page "user.php?u=X" should be open only when email and password are entered correctly. But in my case when I sent correct data and incorrect data it will be the same... To sum up - correct data should redirected me to user.php?u=X and incorrect should display an error message below the form.

What do you think about it?

### Index.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["e"])){
    include_once("../db/db_fns.php");
    $e = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['e']);
    $p = md5($_POST['p']);
    $ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));
    if($e == "" || $p == ""){
        echo "loginfailed";
        exit();
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE email='$e' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
        $db_id = $row[0];
        $db_username = $row[1];
        $db_pass_str = $row[2];
        if($p != $db_pass_str){
            echo "loginfailed";
            exit();
        } else {
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $db_id;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $db_username;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $db_pass_str;
            setcookie("id", $db_id, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", "", "", TRUE);
            setcookie("user", $db_username, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", "", "", TRUE);
            setcookie("pass", $db_pass_str, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", "", "", TRUE); 
            $sql = "UPDATE users SET ip='$ip', lastlogin=now() WHERE username='$db_username' LIMIT 1";
            $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
            echo $db_username;
            exit();
        }
    }
    exit();
}
?>
<script src="../js/main.js"></script>
<script src="../js/ajax.js"></script>
<script src="login.js"></script>
  <form id="loginform" onsubmit="return false;">
    <div>Email Address:</div>
    <input type="text" id="email" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="88">
    <div>Password:</div>
    <input type="password" id="password" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="100">
    <br /><br />
    <button id="loginbtn" onclick="login()">Log In</button> 
    <p id="status"></p>
    <a href="#">Forgot Your Password?</a>
  </form>
```

### login.js

```
function emptyElement(x) {
    _(x).innerHTML = "";
}

function login() {
    var e = _("email").value;
    var p = _("password").value;
    if (e == "" || p == "") {
        _("status").innerHTML = "Fill out all of the form data";
    } else {
        _("loginbtn").style.display = "none";
        _("status").innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "index.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                if(ajax.responseText == "loginfailed") {
                    _("status").innerHTML = "Login unsuccessful, please try again.";
                    _("loginbtn").style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    window.location = "user.php?u="+ajax.responseText;
                }
            }
        }
        ajax.send("e="+e+"&p="+p);
    }
}
```

Comment: MD5 is not secure.  Use bcrypt or PBKDFv2.

Comment: hmm.. there are plenty of good login frameworks out there.. putting the password, encrypted/hashed or otherwise, in session and cookies seems like a poor design. I'll post my generic login class

Comment: Try echoing the variables that are sent to the server and retrieved from the database. You can read the response back in your dev tools network monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : 
Try to alert `ajax.responseText` and see if it return proper result without an error. Also user `trim` before comparing responsetext like this : `if(ajax.responseText.trim() == "loginfailed")`
Why you are not using Jquery as it is very simple and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing return and therefore your form is submitting regardless. Don't forget to have the login() function return false so it doesn't submit.

try `<button id="loginbtn" onclick="return login();">Log In</button>`